# Array list with nested if statements

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Hey guys i am trying to create an android program using voice recognition and have an error with initialising a program inside the nested if statement. Please Help.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    startvoiceRecognition();
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        ArrayList program = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        //mlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));
        mlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MainActivity>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));
        //proglist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MainActivity>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, program));
        if (matches.contains("start")){
            start();
        }
        else if (matches.contains("program")){
            program();
            if (matches.contains("cotton")) {
                cotton();
            }
        }
        else if (matches.contains("stop")) {
            stop();
        }
```

The `matches.contains("cotton")` has to be executed after the program but does not execute and is it possible to use switch case with arraylist ?

P.S- started android studio and java 1 week ago.

Comment: from your condition arraylist must contain both..`program` and `cotton`..

Comment: first it must contain program and then the next arraylist must have cotton. The 'program' creates another arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Your "cotton" if statement is double nested, perhaps this is your issue? As it is now to get to the "cotton" portion of the statement, you have to first satisfy the condition of matches.contains("program"). In other words, your "cotton" condition is actual equivalent to needing a match for both "cotton" and "program"

Not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but a single bracket will bring your "cotton" statement out of that second level of nesting. ie:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    startvoiceRecognition();
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        ArrayList program = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        //mlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));
        mlist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MainActivity>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches));
        //proglist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<MainActivity>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, program));
        if (matches.contains("start")){
            start();
        } else if (matches.contains("program")){
            program();
        }
        if (matches.contains("cotton")) {
            cotton();
        }
        }
        else if (matches.contains("stop")) {
            stop();
        }
```

Comment: This does work but i need it to function after it satisfies the condition of matches having program and then having  it to search for cotton in the next intent.